# Could not find a part of the path : Process the list of files

Tags: c#, .net

I m getting this error, i couldnt understand why :

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
```

> Could not find a part of the path '\Dti-w2k8\dti\DTI Shared Folder_BACKUPS\Bryan's Documents\DTI Projects\Code and Programs\Ditcher Install Files_DTI_Software\Development\AngleBlaster V5 (MJ)\Install COM3\AngleBlaster 20140407 v5_0_1_1 Install COM3\bin\Release\Pictures\buttons\optionA\Cal_Old'.

I checked the file path and i found the Directory on my explorer.
Can i get some help please

Comment: Maybe the path is too long. If i remember right, it can`t be longer that 260 characters

Comment: this is exactly 259

Comment: Trying to execute the code, I get the following error: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: blah.. yes i just figure out thank you :). otherwise if you use the last framework 4.6 name issue its resolved there.
Thank you (y)